# how to limit excel column to limited number of words

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'm working with VBA, Excel. I have some set of words, say 10.

When I choose a particular column, then what ever I enter in that coulmn must be from those selected set of words.

It's like dropdown list but I really donot want to use dropdown list. This must be done to a column(or set of cells).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you should be able to do it just like dropdown list but without in-cell dropdown option marked. Its an option that is automaticly marked when you validate column by list in validation form.

Comment: can you be some more clear. what is out-in cell dropdown option.

Comment: Thanks @Poof. It's working but the can we customize the error alert box that comes after entering a wrong value

Comment: Yes. While creating validation there are 3 tabs: Settings,Input message,Error alert. Select the third one and there you can change the message that will appear after inputting wrong value.

Comment: I didn't realise you could do the validation without displaying the dropdown. Handy to know but I'm not sure if I'll ever find an application for it. Unless, maybe, you have the validation words in a range immediately above the cells you are filling to take advantage of autocomplete.